# vue.js: scoping custom option merge strategies instead going global

Tags: vue.js

Good Day Fellows,

**Quick summary**: how can I use custom option merge strategies on an individual basis per component and not globaly?

**My problem**:
I am extending my components via Mixins and it is working great so far. However, while it is working great with the likes of component methods, I often need to override some lifecycle hooks, like mounted, created, etc.  The catch is, Vue - by default - queues them up in an array and calls them after another. This is of course defined by Vues default merge strategies.

However in some specific cases I do need to override the hook and not have it stack. I know I can customize Vue.config.optionMergeStrategies to my liking, but I want the mergeStrategy customized on a per component basis and not applying it globably.

My naive approach on paper was to create a higher function which stores the original hooks, applies my custom strategy, calls my component body and after that restores Vues original hooks.

Let's say like this

```
export default function executeWithCustomMerge(fn) {
    const orig = deep copy Vue.config.optionMergeStrategies;


    Vue.config.optionMergeStrategies.mounted = (parent, child) => [child];

    fn();
    Vue.config.optionMergeStrategies = deep copy orig;
```

}

And here's it in action

```
executeWithCustomMerge(() => {
    Vue.component('new-comp', {
         mixins: [Vue.component("old-comp")],
    },
    mounted() {
       //i want to override my parent thus I am using a custom merge strategy
    });
});
```

Now, this is not going to work out because restoring the original hook strategies still apply on a global and will be reseted before most hooks on my component are being called.

I wonder what do I need to do to scope my merge strategy to a component.

Answer (score 2):

I had a look at [optionMergeStrategies](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#optionMergeStrategies) in more detail and found this interesting quote from the docs (emphasis mine):

> The merge strategy receives the value of that option defined on the parent and child instances as the first and second arguments, respectively. **The context Vue instance is passed as the third argument**.

So I thought it would be straightforward to implement a custom merging strategy that inspects the Vue instance and looks at its properties to decide which strategy to use. Something like this:

```
const mergeCreatedStrategy = Vue.config.optionMergeStrategies.created;
Vue.config.optionMergeStrategies.created = function strategy(toVal, fromVal, vm) {
  if (vm.overrideCreated) {
    // If the "overrideCreated" prop is set on the component, discard the mixin's created()
    return [vm.created];
  }
  return mergeCreatedStrategy(toVal, fromVal, vm);
};
```

It turns out though that the 3rd argument (vm) is not set when the strategy function is called for components. It's a new bug! See https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/9623

So I found another way to inform the merge strategy on what it should do. Since JavaScript functions are first-class objects, [they can have properties and methods just like any other object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions). Therefore, we can set a component's function to override its parents by setting a property on it and looking for its value in the merge strategy like so:

```js
Vue.mixin({
  created() {
    this.messages.push('global mixin hook called');
  }
});

const mixin = {
  created() {
    this.messages.push('mixin hook called');
  },
};

const mergeCreatedStrategy = Vue.config.optionMergeStrategies.created;
Vue.config.optionMergeStrategies.created = function strategy(toVal, fromVal) {
  if (fromVal.overrideOthers) {
    // Selectively override hooks injected from mixins
    return [fromVal];
  }
  return mergeCreatedStrategy(toVal, fromVal);
};

const app = {
  el: '#app',
  mixins: [mixin],
  data: { messages: [] },
  created() {
    this.messages.push('component hook called');
  },
};
// Comment or change this line to control whether the mixin created hook is applied
app.created.overrideOthers = true;

new Vue(app);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <h1>Messages from hooks</h1>
  <p v-for="message in messages">{{ message }}</p>
</div>
```